# Box shadow isn't working on Android

Tags: javascript, jquery

For unknown reasons box shadow isn't working on android.

I tried to use

```
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #F3D280;
box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #F3D280;
```

What alternative can be used there if there is no solution of using box shadow?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://caniuse.com/css-boxshadow), box-shadow should be supported in Android.

**Edit:** on second thought, do you really need box shadow? The CSS you provided is identical to a 2px solid border, like this:

```
border: 2px solid #F3D280;
```